# Read .TXT into ListBox in realtime

Tags: wpf, listbox

I am reading a large Txt document into a WPF app for some serious swap/replacemnt operations. The files are actually 3D STP models so they are fairly large, but im working with them as raw text for this project. The files are read into List to avoid having to open them multiple times, and to make comparisons easier.

Anyway, I'm trying to get the listbox to scroll dynamically as lines are added to it, ala a console window so the user can see that something is happening since calculations can take a bit of time depending on filesize. I also added a progress bar to count away as the total line number is read through.

Neither my progress bar, nor ListBox seem to update as work progresses though. The final output simply lands in the listbox completed, and the progress bar goes from 0-max at the same time.

This is the gist of what I am doing, which is fairly simple:

```
   foreach (string Line in OriginalSTPFile.Lines)
   {
       string NewLine = EvaluateString(Line);  //string the modified to whatever here
       pBar.Value++;   //increment progressbar

       OutputWindow.Items.Add(NewLine);  //add line to the ListBox
   }
```

I just want the listbox an progress bar to update in realtime as progress changes. I tried using:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => OutputWindow.Items.Add(NewLine));
```

But got the same results. Do I need a more elaborate method of multithreading here? I assumed the first method would've worked since I wasn't generating any cross-thread exceptions either.

Comment: What do you mean with "real time"? What is fairly large? Please also post the step function that updates the Progress bar.

Comment: As in, whenever a line is "evaluated" the result is printed into the ListBox immediately and the progess bar moves accordingly. The should happen before the next line is evaluated. Right now, the program hangs for a moment, then all the information appears at the same time.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. It will help you for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article will give you all the code that you need.

[Backgroundworker with Progressbar](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/)

It describes very well what to do and which elements to use.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke signals to invoke a method on the Dispatcher's thread. However, that's essentially like a post message, as it won't occur while the main thread is locked up doing work. And until the main thread is available again, it won't update the UI visually, even if you change values.

You'll need to perform the work in a background thread.

But to update the UI, you'll have to do so on the UI's main thread. This is a limitation of WPF. This is why you were directed to Dispatcher. I'm guessing someone assumed your work was already on a background thread.

To create a thread, you use `Thread.Start` passing it a delegate to perform. If you use a anonymous delegate or a lambda, you can refer to variables on the stack, but be aware that they will persist until the delegate quits. This is why you cannot use reference variables in a anonymous delegate.

Backgroundworker is a special type of background thread. It automates some of the expectations of a worker thread (notifying of completion, and updating on progress), but you can achieve the same results without it.

To update the UI during the thread's process, you'll need for that thread to be able to access the main UI thread. You can do that by passing it a dispatcher, referring to a dispatcher from outside the anonymous delegate, or by an object that contains a dispatcher. You can always read values from any object on any thread, so accessing the dispatcher by UIElement on another thread is fine.

To update the UI, you'll call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` with a delegate that entails the work to perform.

Here's psuedo-code of the overall scheme

```
class TestProgress
{
    ProgressBar _ProgressBar;

    void DoWork()
    {
        var worker = (Action)(() =>
        {
            int progress = 0;
            // do stuff, delta is change in progress
            progress += delta;
            _ProgressBar.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                _ProgressBar.Value = progress;
            }));
        });
        Thread.Start(worker);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both answers were excellent, I wish I could pick both! Stangely enough, the display still wouldn't update unless I included a Thread.Sleep(1) in my DoWork method. It executes in the background and I can move the UI, but it doesn't update dynamically.

Comment: Try Invoke instead of BeginInvoke

Comment: That was it! I have a lot to lean about multithreading! Thank you

Comment: Please note that a Sleep(0) or Sleep(1) causes a context change. This is what you see there.